# Material-UI. How to override library two classes selector with my custom one class

Tags: html, css, material-ui

I have a `Grid` element with applied custom CSS class `addPanel` (using makeStyles). In the rended HTML it looks like `.makeStyles-addPanel-21` class applied to `div` element. But Material-UI itself, additionally applies its own style to this `div` which looks like this`.MuiGrid-spacing-xs-3 > .MuiGrid-item`. 
Of course, Material-UI 2-classes selector has higher specificity than my 1-class selector, so it overides mine. 
[image]
How can I apply 2 or 3-classes selector to my `Grid` to increase CSS selector specificity and thus override Material-UI class?
Here is an simplified code:

```
import React from 'react';
import {makeStyles} from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import Grid from "@material-ui/core/Grid";
import TextField from '@material-ui/core/TextField';

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
    addPanel: {
        paddingTop: "44px",
        paddingLeft: "50px",
    },
}));

const ManageLocales = (props) => {
    const classes = useStyles();

    return (
        <Grid container spacing={3}>
            <Grid item container xs={8} spacing={3} className={classes.addPanel}>
                <Grid item>
                    <TextField 
                        label="Add country" 
                        variant="outlined" 
                        size="small"
                    />
                </Grid>                            
            </Grid>
        </Grid>
    );
}
export default ManageLocales;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a solution. According to this https://material-ui.com/styles/advanced/#with-material-ui-core 
you can create 2, 3 etc. classes selectors using `"&.someMegaClass"` syntax. So the solution will look like this:

```
const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
    someClass: {
        "&.addPanel": {
            paddingTop: "44px",
            paddingLeft: "50px",
        }
    }
}));
```

This code will create the CSS selector which look like this: `.makeStyles-someClass-22.addPanel` 
To apply this classes to your `div` use this syntax 
 `` className={`${classes.someClass} addPanel`} `` 
 or this syntax 
 `className={classes.someClass + " addPanel"}` 
 This is a way to effectively override any library CSS selector just creating your own selectors with higher specificity.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding

```
::ng-deep {


}
```

surrounding your custom classes in your css file. It should prioritize your customizations over anything native to material UI.

Comment: ng-deep looks like Angular directive. But I use React